Shape of graph of energy in S.H.M
I'm confused to whether the graph of KE/PE of a simple harmonic motion system is sinusoidal or not


those are my best sketches but if unclear, the blue one is in a shape of a sine wave.
this question also applies to the shape of power/time graph of an A.C supply would it be sinusoidal or not? and also whichever is the right graph, why?

I know that the y axis says Kinetic energy, but I drew the graph for potential energy

max amp means max amplitude



to the answers that have been saying the blue graph is correct, how does that align with this graph? because the "continuation" of this graph doesn't look like it could be sinusoidal. Is it because the x axis is displacement and not time?

Do these identities help? $\cos^2 x=\tfrac 1 2 (1+\cos 2x)$, $\sin^2 x=\tfrac 1 2 (1-\cos 2x)$

For a simple harmonic motion we have
$$x(t)=x_\max\sin(\omega t+\phi_0)$$
$$\dot{x}(t)=x_\max\omega\cos(\omega t+\phi_0)$$
Hence we get the kinetic energy
$$\begin{align}
E_\text{kin}&=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2(t) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}mx_\max^2\omega^2\cos^2(\omega t+\phi_0)
   &&; \text{use }\cos^2\alpha=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos 2\alpha) \\
&=\frac{1}{4}mx_\max^2\omega^2(1+\cos(2\omega t+2\phi_0))  
\end{align}$$
and the potential energy
$$\begin{align}
E_\text{pot}&=\frac{1}{2}kx^2(t) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}kx_\max^2\sin^2(\omega t+\phi_0)
  && ;\text{use }\sin^2\alpha=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos 2\alpha) \\
&=\frac{1}{4}kx_\max^2(1-\cos(2\omega t+2\phi_0))
\end{align}$$
So in both cases you got a sinusoidal oscillation of
the partial energies between $0$ and a maximum with the double
frequency ($2\omega$), like in your second diagram.

i added another part to the question if you can answer that

To make this question relevant to more people, i think you should add more description to your question. For instance, what kind of system is it? You mentioned A.C. supply, so is it a simple harmonic system in the electrical or mechanical domain?
To your question, the first figure looks like an electrical rectified voltage amplitude by just blind guessing, a sine wave, so not energy vs time, but rather voltage vs time.
Second figure would look more like an energy graph vs displacement of a typical simple harmonic oscillator, a sin square wave. However, without further information, it's very difficult to answer your question. Please add more information.
